# Angular passing directive to child element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-routerlink

I am building a navbar for my Angular app and I've decided to make a `nav-item` component for containing links inside of the navbar. I'd like to be able to pass a `routerLink` directive to it and have that directive get passed to the `a` element within the `nav-item` component.

My `nav-item` component looks like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-item',
  template: `
<li><a>
  <ng-content #wrapper></ng-content>
</a></li>
`
})
export class NavItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') content: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

I want to be able to use the `nav-item` component like this.

```
<nav-item routerLink="/login">Login</nav-item>
```

Is there any way to pass to pass a `routerLink` directive from the `nav-item` component to its `a` element? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know if it's possible but you could definitely pass a function that can be assigned to <a (click)="passedFunction()" and then function will call router.navigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood your question. But you could do something like that

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nav-item',
  template: `
<li><a>
  <ng-content #wrapper></ng-content>
</a></li>
`
})
export class NavItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') content: ElementRef;
  @Input('link') link: string;



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      //Inject router on constructor
      this.rourter.navigate(link)
  }
}
```

And after that you call

```
<nav-item link="/login">Login</nav-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work, and it should support passing a string link or URL tree.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-item',
  template: `
<li><a [routerLink]="routerLink">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</a></li>
`
})
export class NavItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() routerLink: string | any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

As a side note, unless you absolutely need the ElementRef, you should not use it for security reasons. Please read the note about it here: https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef